# EAS Update not detecting EXPO_PUBLIC environment variables

Tags: expo, eas

I am attempting to setup my app to utilize EXPO_PUBLIC environment variables with EAS Update.
https://docs.expo.dev/eas-update/environment-variables/

My eas.json:

```json
{
  "build": {
    "base": {
      "node": "18.18.0",
      "yarn": "1.22.19",
      "android": {
        "image": "default",
        "env": {
          "PLATFORM": "android"
        }
      },
      "ios": {
        "image": "latest",
        "env": {
          "PLATFORM": "ios"
        }
      }
    },
    "development": {
      "extends": "base",
      "developmentClient": true,
      "android": {
        "distribution": "internal",
        "withoutCredentials": true
      },
      "ios": {
        "simulator": true
      }
    },
    "staging": {
      "channel": "staging",
      "extends": "base",
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": { "buildType": "apk" },
      "ios": { "simulator": false }
    },
    "production": {
      "channel": "production",
      "extends": "base"
    }
  }
}
```

I have 3 environment files:

1. .env.development
2. .env.staging
3. .env.production

Each of these env files contains 1 environment variable EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL which is the url of my api.

**The Problem**

When i run the app locally using `yarn expo start`
My console outputs

```bash
env: load .env.development
env: export EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL
```

which is correct.

HOWEVER, when I run `eas update --channel staging`
My console outputs

```bash
✔ Provide an update message: … stable [expo-cli] 
env: load .env.production [expo-cli] 
env: export EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL
```

I have tried messing around with the config files. I've scoured the docs multiple times with no results. I am expecting eas to use the .env.staging config when i run `eas update --channel staging`